# Get div's size with mooTools

Tags: javascript, dom, mootools

I have some `<div id="text">abc</div>`.
Is it possible to get it's size using `JS`/`mooTools`  (`width` and `height`) when I did not set it with `CSS` ?

Comment: Have you heard of the awesomeness that is jQuery?

Comment: However I ask about awesomeless mooTools ;-)

Comment: Are you guys kidding me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Dimensions#Element:getSize

```
var size = myElement.getSize();
[size.x, size.y]
```

Comment: It returns [0, 0] in this case.

Comment: Guess you need http://mootools.net/docs/more/Element/Element.Measure .   The jQuery API design is far more "KISS" and easier to use imo.

Comment: that is because Element.Measure has FA to do with what mootools methods you'd actually use for this. `element.getCoordinates()` or `element.getSize()` work fine but will fall short on kissing you. it will work, PROVIDING that the element is--in fact--injected in the DOM and that the script block that computes it is either a `domready` callback or simply run after the element's content and dimensions are done being modified. if you have any problems, there's always www.jsfiddle.net, port the block of code you are having issues with there and post the link

Comment: `hello? yes. my microwave does not work. oh... have you tried jquery?`

Answer (score 3):

```
$('myElement').getStyle('width');
```

returns  the width of  that element.

```
$('myElement').setStyle('width', 'value');
```

u can  change it

thats  all :)

Comment: If element's size is set in CSS it works - otherwise it does not. In that case works only `Element.Measure`.

Comment: i am getting the output as '200px,200px,200px,200px,200px,200px,200px,200px,200px,200px,200px,200px', i am using this '$("#slider_more li").getStyle('width')'...